# NPE in UIComponentBase#getRenderer() after migration from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I migrated my web application from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0. The logout page which was working in the previous version throws `NullPointerException` in JSF 2.0. Rest of the things are  working as expected.

Below is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.getRenderer(UIComponentBase.java:1268)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:788)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot$1.invokeRoot(AjaxViewRoot.java:396)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:229)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processDecodes(AjaxViewRoot.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:359)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:371)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SessionFixationProtectionFilter.doFilterHttp(SessionFixationProtectionFilter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:371)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:371)
    at org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
```

My `logout.xhtml` looks like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=#{bean.logoutUrl}"></meta>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Logging you out...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely upgrade my JSF 2 version. I had the same problem some time ago using JSF 2.0.2 and it went away when upgradin to JSF 2.0.3. The problem was described in JSF 2.0.3 release notes.